BigQuery remove same ID Numbers
I Have a simple table:



ID




556


556


38


93


826



I need to query above table using Google BigQuery and get below results by removing same ID numbers.
Outbut:



ID




556


38


93


826



Thanks All for help.
Failed to get this desire output.

If you just want to view the output as you have shown it, you only need a distinct select:
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM yourTable;

